Mensajes de Alerta para plataforma iOS UIAlertView implementada con DependencyService en Xamarin.Forms
Tengo el siguiente codigo en el proyecto compartido
using UIKit;

void clicked_folio_manual(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var alert = new UIAlertView();
    alert.Title = "Informacion";
    alert.Message = "Indique el Folio de Orden de Compra";
    alert.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput;
    alert.AddButton("OK");
    alert.Dismissed += buscar_folio_manual;
    alert.Show();
}

async void buscar_folio_manual(object sender, UIButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var alert_parent = sender as UIAlertView;
    string folio_orden = alert_parent.GetTextField(0).Text;
    folio_orden = folio_orden.PadLeft(7, '0');

    if (ValidarFolio(folio_orden))
    {
        Clases.Global.folio_orden_ = folio_orden;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page_Head_OrdenCompra());
    }
}

Al ejecutar mi proyecto desde visual studio para Mac, no tengo ningun inconveniente, pero cuando lo intento ejecutar desde windows, me aparece el error: The type or namespace name UIAlertView could bot be found.
he realizado la implementacion con DependencyService como lo explican aqui, y lo he realizado sin ningun problema, cuando se trata de mostrar solo un mensaje de alerta, pero cuando intento agregar el AlertViewStyle y el Dismissed, no encuentro la forma de hacer la implementacion.
